# How to implement a prime number checker into an array where i need to count the number of primes?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, primes, divide

I have an array which contains 20 numbers and I have to count the primes in the array. I came up with this code (its a simple prime checker), but when I try to implement it into the array using a `for` loop, it won't work.

```
int primcounter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++)
{
    int divider = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j <= array[i]; j++)
    {
        if (array[i] % j == 0)
        {
            divider++;
        }
        else
        { }
    }

    if (divider == 2)
    {
        primcounter++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(primcounter + "Primes are in the array");
```

The goal is to test every number in the array if it's a prime, and if it is, then increment `primcounter` by `1`.

Comment: Does the prime checking part of your code work, isolated?

Comment: Also, when you say "won't work", what **exactly** do you mean? Can you post a [mcve]? Give an example of input, the output, and what you expected?

Comment: technically that part goes with a simple user input not with an arrays ith element so yeah, it worked

Comment: " loop it won't work." could you expound on what that means?

Comment: Could it be that you're getting an array index out of bounds exception because of `i <= array.Length`, which should be `<`, and not `<=` ?

Comment: Generally, when I want to work with a small number of prime numbers, I look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: So the input is 20 numbers by the user, and it stored in an array. that part works perfectly. Then i need to test every of them if its a prime, so the expected output is a simple number between 0 and 20

Comment: Yeah, when i try to run it, it writes "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
"

But at the second for loop for `(int j = 1; j <= array[i]; j++)`

Comment: Can you give a sample input, the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: Yeah the point of the check algo is to check if there is more than 2 dividers, and if not, then it will be considered as a prime

Comment: Like @LasseV.Karlsen mentioned the problem is `i <= array.Length, which should be <, and not <= ` this is the result --> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" :: arrays are index zero based. start counting with "0"

Comment: sample input is just random positive number, like 1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and the expected output is the count of primes so here is 3 but i don't get any output since the code gives the exception error

Comment: Now i modified the code and it only contains < operators rather than <=, and it works now but if i enter the number 7, 20 times it gives back that i have 0 primes

Comment: I tried a quick check, it is showing 20 primes correctly with your code+the fix you did above. See here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/nzUHsC

Comment: Thimmu Lanka Thanks, it works. Alltho i don't know how did you make it, but it works fine. Thanks for it!

Comment: I strongly suggest, even if it's not required by your assignment, that you create a `new List<int>`.  Every time you find a prime `Add` it to the list.  In the end, you could write them out.  Even if you don't, it will help you debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement as extension method with linq

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Math
    {
        public static bool IsPrime(this int candidate)
        {
            for (int denominator = 2; denominator < candidate - 1; denominator++) 
                if (candidate % denominator == 0) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new List<int>() { 
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 
            }.Where(candidate => candidate.IsPrime()).Count());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not completely right. According to your code "1" would be prime. And what is to stop someone from entering "0" as a candidate?  According to your code "0" would also be prime.